# Java 8 stream - avoid NPE

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I want to get the following data from:

```
MyObject.builder()
    .lastUpdated(tuple.getT2().isEmpty() ? null : tuple.getT2().get(0).getLastUpdated().toInstant())
...
...
.build()
```

`tuple.getT2().get(0).getLastUpdated()` can be null...

I tried:

```
.lastUpdated(
                        tuple.getT2().stream()
                            .map(Optional::ofNullable)
                            .findFirst()
                            .flatMap(Function.identity())
                            .map(metadata -> metadata.getLastUpdated().toInstant()) //NPE
                            .orElse(null))
```

but I get NPE in the line

```
.map(metadata -> metadata.getLastUpdated().toInstant())
```

Comment: Maybe `.map(metadata->metadata.getLastUpdated()).map(date->date.toInstant()).orElse(null)`?

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `map` lambda is not some magic place where NPEs do not happen. If you have a thing that could be null, you need to map to it to avoid NPEs. Replace this call:

```
.map(metadata -> metadata.getLastUpdated().toInstant())
```

with

```
.map(TypeOfMetadata::getLastUpdated)
.map(TypeOfGetLastUpdated::toInstant)
```

This will make it use the `orElse` value if `metadata.getLastUpdated()` is null.